# How to Dynamically Adjust Contents of Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I was wondering if there's any sort of way that I'd be able to dynamically adjust the contents of a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`? I have a view within the collapsing toolbar that gets partially covered up when the toolbar is collapsed:

[image]

As you can see, the logo at the very top is being covered up (the "d" in "reader"). This is because in the XML I have for my layout, I've set the bottom margin to 20dp and this margin remains the same whether the toolbar is expanded or collapsed.

My thought was to dynamically adjust the bottom margin depending on if the collapsing toolbar is expanded (use a 20dp bottom margin) or collapsed (set the bottom margin to 0dp). The `AppBarLayout` has an [OnOffsetChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener.html), so I figured this would be a great way to achieve this.

From my understanding, in order to adjust the margins of the logo, I need to programatically adjust the `LayoutParams` of the `ImageView` which contains the logo. I've attempted to do this here:

```
    final ImageView logo = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_article_detail_logo);

    final CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams) logo.getLayoutParams();

    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_article_detail_app_bar_layout);
    // This is the total range of the AppBarLayout
    int scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
    // If scrollRange is negative, then that means that the app bar is completely collapsed
    final int collapsedOffset = scrollRange * -1;
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            // If the app bar is completely collapsed, we want to remove the bottom margin
            if (verticalOffset == collapsedOffset) {
                layoutParams.setMargins(layoutParams.leftMargin, layoutParams.topMargin, layoutParams.rightMargin, 0);
                logo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                logo.requestLayout();
            }
            // If the app bar is fully expanded, we'll apply the bottom margin
            else if (verticalOffset == 0){
                layoutParams.setMargins(layoutParams.leftMargin, layoutParams.topMargin, layoutParams.rightMargin, getBottomMargin());
                logo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                logo.requestLayout();
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that going this route, my margins aren't being applied for some reason. The `getBottomMargin()` method is meant to return the amount of bottom margin in pixels:

```
private int getBottomMargin() {
    Resources resources = getResources();
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            resources.getDimension(R.dimen.app_bar_logo_bottom_margin),
            resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

And even though I have my margins applied in XML, as well as adjusting them dynamically in Java, my logo doesn't have either the left or bottom margin applied correctly:

[image]

FYI, the screen shot earlier in the question was prior to dynamically trying to adjust the margins of the logo.

So my main question is: What am I doing wrong here? Can I achieve what I'm hoping to with the approach I'm taking? I know that the simplest route would be to just adjust the height and width of the logo to something smaller than `wrap_content`. However, I feel like there's a better way to do this (making the logo smaller seems too easy).

If it helps at all, here is the part of my layout XML that contains the `AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_article_detail_app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height_expanded"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/app_bar_height_minimum">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/fragment_article_detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/keyline_screen_edge_left"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height_minimum"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/action_up"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/keyline_screen_edge_left"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_article_detail_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_bar_logo_bottom_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/keyline_inner_left"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to get this to work myself. I made a few changes to both the `OnOffsetChangedListener` as well as `getBottomMargin()`:

```
mLogo = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_article_detail_logo);
final CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams) mLogo.getLayoutParams();

AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_article_detail_app_bar_layout);
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

        // If toolbar is collapsed, we'll remove the bottom margin
        if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) == appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()){
            layoutParams.setMargins(layoutParams.leftMargin, layoutParams.topMargin, layoutParams.rightMargin, 0);
            mLogo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }

        /*
        Otherwise, we'll add the bottom margin back in. I could have kept just as a plain
        else statement. However, scrolling started to feel jittery since this was being
        called each time app bar is being expanded. The additional if() has been added to
        ensure that the bottom margin is only added once.
         */
        else if (layoutParams.bottomMargin != getBottomMargin()) {
            layoutParams.setMargins(layoutParams.leftMargin, layoutParams.topMargin, layoutParams.rightMargin, getBottomMargin());
            mLogo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }
});
```

The issue with my previous attempt was with the following:

```
int scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
final int collapsedOffset = scrollRange * -1;
```

These variables were being set outside of onOffsetChanged(), or rather before the `OnOffsetChangedListener` was being added to the `AppBarLayout`. I don't have a very firm understanding of how the Android framework lays out the UI. However, the one thing that I do know is that it makes several attempts of laying out the UI until everything is positioned correctly. When I was debugging my previous attempt, `scrollRange`was always 0 (which made `collapsedOffset` inherently 0 too). My guess is that the app bar wasn't completely laid out yet when I was setting those variables, so that may be what was causing them to always be 0. I'm not totally sure on that though.

The other additional change that I made was to `getBottomMargin()`:

```
private int getBottomMargin() {

    return getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.app_bar_logo_bottom_margin);
}
```

I'm unsure of why the other version of `getBottomMargin()` didn't work. But for whatever reason, it made the bottom margin much bigger than it really should have been.

Those are the most significant changes that I made to my previous implementation of this. If anyone has ideas for how to make this a bit more efficient, or to make the adjustment to the bottom margin be a smoother transition, please provide your input. Hope this can help someone else out in need :)